# create a vector from a long table for each variable

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a following table

```
Name Subject
Alex Math
Alex Physics
Ann  History
Ann  Literature
Ann  Social Sciences
```

I want to transform this table into to a table with two rows so it would look like:

```
Name Subject
Alex c(Math, Physics)
Ann  c(History, Literature, Social Sciences)
```

The purpose of this transformation is to create generate all combinations of elements in the vector:

```
Math Physics
History Literature
History Social Sciences
Literature Social Sciences
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()`function

```
  dat=read.table(text="Name Subject
            Alex Math
            Alex Physics
            Ann  History
            Ann  Literature
            Ann  'Social Sciences'",h=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

  aggregate(Subject~Name,dat,I)
   Name                              Subject
 1 Alex                        Math, Physics
 2  Ann History, Literature, Social Sciences
```